# Populate the WTF Form Field value using Form inbuilt Function

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

Need to populate the choices of the SelectField (WTF Form) using a function. I do not want to add the choices data in the `SelectField` itself.

```
class TestForm(FlaskForm):
      dropdown = SelectField(choices=[])
      
      def form_overrided_method(self):
           self.dropdown.choices = [('A', 'A')]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply values to the choices in the `__init__` function of your `TestForm` class:

```
class TestForm(FlaskForm):
    dropdown = SelectField('Dropdown', coerce=int)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TestForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.dropdown.choices = [(1, 'A'),...]
```